# How to remove Recent View List view in lightning

Tags: apex, configuration

Is it possible to hide the recently viewed contacts list view (dropdown) from my users?

It really confuses them, as this list view doesn't even seem to be ordered in order of recently viewed items?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove it. However, you can change the default. You can achieve this using the feature ["Pinned Lists"](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_lex_pinned_lists.htm). This was introduced in Spring'19. With pinned lists, you can make any list of choice as a new default. This gives the ability for an end-user to set their own personal default as the best option.

To pin an unpinned list, click its pin icon. To pin a different list, select the list view and pin it instead. The default pinned list for all objects is Recently Viewed.

This feature was delivered based on this [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cM0fQAE)

[image]